# MVC 5 - Open popup on table row click with passing viewmodel

Tags: popup, modal-dialog, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having a table in an MVC view like this:

```
@model FoodCalculator.Models.MealViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Show Meals";
}

<h2>Meals</h2>

    <table class="table table-striped table-hover mealDetailsTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>
            No
        </th>
        <th>
            Meal name
        </th>
        <th>
            Meal type name
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Meals)
        {
            <tr id="tableRowClick" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Value" data-target="#mealModal">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value.MealID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value.MealName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value.MealType.MealTypeName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mealModal">Details</button>
        }   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And on a row click popup shows up :

```
@model FoodCalculator.Models.MealViewModel

<div class="modal fade" id="mealDetails" style="display: none; border: 5px solid black; padding: 10px;" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CmapModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Meal details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" id="mealID" name="mealDetail" style="display: none;" />

            @if (Model != null)
            {
                <h3> Meal id : @Model.SelectedMealID</h3>

                    @Html.Action("ShowMealDetails", "Home", new { mealID = Model.SelectedMealID })
            }
```

Close
                Save changes

This is all enabled by the javascript :

```
$('.mealDetailsTable').find('tr[data-id]').on('click', function () {
$('#mealDetails').modal('show');

var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('id');

$("#mealID").val(getIdFromRow);
});
```

And what I'm trying to do is passing viewmodel with currently clicked row data to a popup, so I could perform further actions.

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your code has issues. You are trying to generate and create a popup HTML for each of the table rows. But the id of 'data-target' attribute remains the same i.e "#mealModal". What this means is, your popup would be binded by default to the first row of the table. You need to dynamically generate and assign an if to the data-target attribute.

1. **View.cshtml**

   ```
   @model FoodCalculator.Models.MealViewModel

    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Show Meals";
       var modelPopupId = "#mealModal" + item.Value.MealID; // Considering MealID is unique
       var modelPopupReferenceId = "#"+ modelPopupId;
     }

      // Inside <tbody> element
    @foreach (var item in Model.Meals)
    {
        <tr id="tableRowClick" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Value" data-target="@modelPopupReferenceId">
        // All other html elements
     }
   ```
2. **Popup**

   ```
   div class="modal fade" id="@modelPopupId" style="display: none; border: 5px solid black; padding: 10px;" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CmapModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   ```